# Group strings together and calculate total

Tags: python, sql, group-by

Have a group of email address and numbers together that are taken out of database in sql using join.

```
SELECT ost_ticket.email, ost_ticket_response.time_taken
FROM ost_ticket
INNER JOIN ost_ticket_response
ON ost_ticket_response.ticket_id=ost_ticket.ticket_id
WHERE time_taken > 0
```

Output

```
('log@tome.ie', 100)
('log@tome.ie', 100)
('log@tome.ie', 10)
('log@tome.ie', 2)
('temp@eircom.net', 30L)
('john@tome-ireland.com', 20L)
('1234567@tome.ie', 1234567L)
('log@tome.ie', 2L)
('log@tome.ie', 2L)
('valerie@tome.ie', 30L)
('john@cmi-tome.com', 10L)
('john@cmi-tome.com', 40L)
```

Want to be able to take all the email address and have total so

```
log@tome.ie = 216
temp@eircom.net = 30
john@tome-ireland.com = 70
1234567@tome.ie = 1234567
john@cmi-tome.com = 50
```

Is it possible to do through sql or after output to do it in python?

Comment: You could just change your SQL query to use SUM and GROUP BY ...

Comment: @Jon Unless you are using an ORM.

Comment: @Swiss . . . the question is tagged with SQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you pull the data from the database, use a query like this:

```
select emailaddress, sum(number) as total
from t
group by emailaddress
```

Comment: Thanks that is perfect

    `SELECT ost_ticket.email, sum(ost_ticket_response.time_taken)
    FROM ost_ticket
    INNER JOIN ost_ticket_response
    ON ost_ticket_response.ticket_id=ost_ticket.ticket_id
    WHERE time_taken > 0
    GROUP BY ost_ticket.email`